# Redux - dispatch actions which happen frequently and bypass the store ?

Tags: redux

I'm building a synthesizer which has a piano-style keyboard UI input.

The keyboard note on/off events can happen quite frequently, these are used to update different parts of the UI and to trigger audio.

What is the frequency threshold which Redux can handle events?  For example, if an event occurs 60 times per second which needs to update some aspect of the UI, how would one handle that using Redux patterns ?

I'm fine with doing this event-ing outside of Redux store entirely if Redux doesn't handle this use case.

Answer (score 2):

Redux doesn't have any magic built into it, it's just an immutable state handler, so whatever javascript can do, redux can do.

What you want to take care of are dom operations, and in your case I'm assuming sound operations.

so your optimizations would be more on the react side, not redux.

if you want help with that, share your relevant react code here.

In general, the place to start optimizing react is [shouldComponentUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)

EDIT:
Here are some links I've found that might give some guidance / inspiration:
https://github.com/xjamundx/react-piano
https://github.com/DanielDeychakiwsky/react-piano

Comment: I wound up just using the package EventEmitter for keyboard events because these particular events have nothing to do with state.  All the other knobs and settings go into the Redux store.

Comment: why not use redux? you find the EE easier? in the future you might want to know what is the state of the sounds. Up to you tho